# How to use this.$scope.$on in typescript,AngularJS1.7

Tags: angularjs, typescript

### I want to capture the emit event from one component into other component

```
export class modifyController implements angular.IComponentController {
      static $inject = ['$scope','$state'];
    constructor(public $scope:ng.IScope,public $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
    this.sendMessage();
      };
    public sendMessage(): void {
    let tempObj = { 'title': 'name', 'id': '1234' }
              this.$scope.$emit('modify',tempObj);
    }
    }
```

## In Other component's controller

```
constructor(public $scope:ng.IScope) {
        //need to write this outside constructor
        this.$scope.$on('modify', (event: ng.IAngularEvent, data: any) => {
            console.log('from ON event...',data);
        });
    }
```

In angularjs1.4 i can directly use $scope.$on() like any other function , but while using this in same way in angularjs1.7 with typescript, i am getting error -*[ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.*

How to use this.$scope.$on in typescript,AngularJS1.7?
Thanks

Comment: There must be something else going on because the implementation of `$scope.$on()` did not change between versions 1.4 and 1.7.

Comment: Yes, true, my question is not that, I want to know, How to use this.$scope.$on in typescript,AngularJS1.7?

Comment: You use it exactly as you have shown in your question: `this.$scope.$on(eventString, (event, args) => {});`. There must be something else going on to be causing the error you're seeing. Maybe if you show more of the the "Other component's controller" code it will shed some light on the issue.